# PHP - Mysql - Issue with results when searching a database table of postcodes with lat and long

Tags: php, mysql

Hoping someone may have an idea. Both of these locations are running their own lat and long. **4870** returns itself as a result, but **4878** doesn't.

When i run this query:

> 4870 (-16.880, 145.750)

`SELECT DISTINCT postcode
         , ( 
            6378 * acos(cos(radians(-16.880)) 
                    * cos(radians(latitude))
                    * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(145.750))
                    + sin(radians(-16.880))
                    * sin(radians(latitude))
                 )
            ) AS distance 
FROM wp_postcodes_geo 
HAVING distance <= 10 
ORDER BY distance`

it returns:
 
`4870    0.00009503960609436035
4878    6.163196895095196
4868    9.156546425369195`

When i run this query: 4878 (-16.840, 145.710)

`SELECT DISTINCT postcode
    , (6378 
        * acos(cos(radians(-16.840))
            *  cos(radians(latitude))
            *  cos(radians(longitude) - radians(145.710))
            +  sin(radians(-16.840))
            *  sin(radians(latitude))
            )
        ) AS distance 
FROM wp_postcodes_geo
HAVING distance <= 10
ORDER BY distance`

It returns:

`4870    6.163196895095196
4879    8.881862597454356`

Both of these places are next to eachother (4870 and 4878, both within a short distance from eachother).

So the data is not consistant, and the search for 4870 itself is returning it's own postcode (4870). but 4878 doesn't.

Anybody know why this would be??? i've tried a bunch of different variations of this mysql query to no avail.

Comment: Incidentally, as a human , I can see why you'd want to refrain from typing out the formula twice, but from the machine's point of view, `WHERE [formula]` is likely to be considerably more efficient than `HAVING distance`.

Comment: Also, FWIW, on my database I have a haversine function for finding metric distances on Earth. It's called geo_distance_km, and it's been posted up here a few times. It doesn't do much for speed, but it sure saves on typing.